# How can we change a default background in react native Slider?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, slider

I'm using [react-native-community/slider](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-slider)
and in my case, i want to disabled user change value so i enable disabled prop,
After enabling it the slider color turned gray.
so how can I change it?

I'm trying to play with library code but i can't find this thing!

**disabled = true**

[image: disabled]

**disabled = false**

*"that's what i want after change disabled to **true**"*

[image]

Code snippet

```
 <Slider
       thumbTintColor="#ebff64"
       maximumTrackTintColor="grey"
       minimumTrackTintColor="#ebff64"
       style={styles.seekBar}
       step={1}
       minimumValue={0}
       maximumValue={this.state.duration}
       value={this.state.currentTime}
       disabled={true}
 />
```

Comment: you want to change color of slider when disabled is true?

Comment: @GauravRoy yes, exactly